# Rails 3.1 Stack level too deep

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Ironically i would like some feed back on a Stack level too deep error!

I've been looking through my code for hours and can't figure out what's wrong!
It occurs when I try to load a javascript-file that is located in the welcome folder, and this is how the code looks like this:

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Project1</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header" >
    <div id="Lorem">
      <b>Lorem
    </div>
    <div id="Ipsum">
      <b><p>Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menuwrapper">
    <div class="tabArea">
      <%= link_to 'Link', {:action => 'update', :controller => 'welcome'},{:class=>"tab",:remote=>true} %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper2">
  </div>
</div>
```

welcome_controller.rb:

```
#coding:utf-8
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController  
  def index

  end
  def update
    respond_to do |format| format.js { render :update => update} end
  end
end
```

update.js.erb:

```
$(alert("Hello"));
```

routes.rb:

```
  get "welcome/index"
  get "welcome/update"
```

Eternally grateful for any ideas of whats causing the overflow! Thanks you.

/Peter

Backtrace:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/92kve.png

Comment: I guess it would be the update.js.erb it's trying to load? Do you then receive the error when clicking on the link_to?

Comment: I'm not sure the respond_to is actually required if you're rendering just the *.erb templates.  It would be if it were something like `format.js { render :json => @thing.to_json }`.

Comment: @agmcload, Yes it's when I'm klicking the link_to I get the error

Comment: @Nick, I've tried without the respond_to too, but the same error still occurs

Comment: @user1132256 can you post the backtrace?

Comment: @user1132256 This still fails if you pull out the whole `respond_to` block statement?  I suspect the `{render :update => update}` is actually attempting to rerender this same action indefinitely.

Comment: @Nick Ah, it works! Thank you! I've been trying the exact same piece of code several times earlier, must have been another fault which was removed when I cleaned up before. Do you have any suggestion how to proceede from here? I'm trying to load this c.html.erb file as a fragment into a div. I've been trying a couple of things from update.js.erb: "$('#wrapper2').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:file => 'c.html.erb') %>");"  & "$('#wrapper2').load('c.html.erb', function() {alert('Load was performed.');});" and a couple of versions. Any obvious reasons it fails? Once again thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user1132256 Glad to hear it works. I would suggest writing up another SO question for the follow-on.

Comment: @Nick Ah sorry. Done I think :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments earlier,

Rails is being told to render the `update` action when rendering for JS format on the `update` action.  The offending code is:

```
{render :update => update}
```